# Вывод инфо о Mikrotik через routeros api Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mikrotik

Есть необходимость получить информацию о температуре Mikrotik, к примеру выполнить команду "/system health print", но никак не могу разобраться, как её записать в routeros_api Python3, пишет, что неверная команда.

Пример кода с командой, который успешно работает и выводит соответствующую информацию:

```
import routeros_api
connection = routeros_api.RouterOsApiPool('192.168.1.1', 
username='admin', password='')
api = connection.get_api()
list_address = api.get_resource('/ip/firewall/address-list/')
test = list_address.get()
print(test)
```

Comment: 1 - для получения данных через api вам скорее всего понадобится метод get, а не print. 2 - не всякий микротик поддерживает отдачу данных о своем состоянии (https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:System/Health#Temperature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось всё просто, я пока пробовал разные вариации, попробовал всё, кроме этого:

```
list_address = api.get_resource('/system/health')
```

Но, комментарий "strawdog" помог :)

Answer (score 1):

Много библиотек работает с MikroTik RouterOS API, но я рекомендую [socialwifi/RouterOS-api](https://github.com/socialwifi/RouterOS-api).
В документации на GitHub есть примеры.

А запрос температуры оборудования имеет такой вид:

```
import routeros_api
connection = routeros_api.RouterOsApiPool(
    host='192.168.1.1',
    username='admin',
    password='',
    port=8728,
    plaintext_login=True
)
temp = 0
temperature = api.get_resource('/system/health/gauges')

for t in temperature.get():
    if t['name'] == 'temperature':
        temp = t['value']
print(temp)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык